# Group css tags within a single div

Tags: html, css, tags

I have a bunch of different CSS edits for different tags within the same div and want to know if there is a way to group them under one div? This is what I have right now:

```
#nav{
    margin: 8px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0,0.4);
}

#nav li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;  
}

#nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 10px 5px auto 5px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 10px
}

#nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I tried putting them within the braces of a single #nav, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, that shortcut is impossible in pure CSS. You may want to look into SASS or LESS, which are metalanguages of CSS, meaning that valid CSS is a subset of valid SASS/LESS. Both of these support constructs where

```
#nav{ 
    thing: example; 
    .child { more: styles; }
    .extra { style: great; } 
}
```

which would be interpreted into CSS as

```
#nav {
    thing: example; }

#nav .child { more: styles;}

#nav .extra { style: great;}
```