# Define CSS Rules in Element Conditional

Tags: css

I'm looking to define CSS like this. Is it possible?

```
#container-id-1
{
   .the_content {           
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: left;           
    }

    .the_footer {
      text-align:center;
    }
}

#container-id-2
{
    .the_content {          
        font-size: 17px;
        text-align: right;          

    }

    .the_footer {
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

I found this resource but since it came out there may be new developments:

[Group css tags within a single div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167972/group-css-tags-within-a-single-div)

Comment: Or Sass http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: Was hoping for a solution that would help us with our WordPress plugin. Since we are developing for WordPress we are preparing for environments we will not be able to install LESS or Sass on. 

Are there any plans to add these powers into CSS?

Comment: Why not just use selectors like `#container-id-1 .the_content `

Comment: We were printing multiple html containers with similar id and class names but with varying style definitions. Because the # of containers and variations of styles were dynamic some styles were overwriting others and I needed a way to make styles unique and was  thinking I could enclose the styles in a CSS conditional when I printed them in the header. But the conditionals do not exist for traditional CSS so we had to discover a different way to make sure there were no conflicts. At the end of the day we gave the <style> containers unique ids and used jquery to delete the ones we did not use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this in straight CSS is to concatenate the names, e.g.:

```
#div1.class1 { //Div with id 'div1' and class 'class1'}
#div1.class2 {}
#div2.class1 {}
#div2.class2 {}
```

Note that this is if the target has both the id `#div1` and the class `class1`

If you want to do child elements, then put a space in between the id and class

```
#div1 .class1 { //Child element of div '#div1' with class 'class1'}
#div1 .class2 {}
#div2 .class1 {}
#div2 .class2 {}
```

---

So to clarify, the first example would apply to a div like this:

```
<div id="div1" class="class1"></div>
```

And the second example will apply to a div like this:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div class="class1"></div> <-----It applies to this one
</div>
```

---

Based on your question, I think you want the second approach. Check **[the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sb2uY/1/)** for my example in your context.

### [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sb2uY/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with normal CSS, you can use dynamic style languages like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) though.

See this for example: [LESS Scopes](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-scope)